# Using gallio in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gallio

Did anyone able to configure gallio in VS2013. I used it in VS2010. 
But I am not able to use it VS2013. I googled a lot and didn't get any solution

Comment: The software works well with VS2010. Since we have VS2012 or 2013 here, we will need to “fool” Gallio to think that it is indeed VS2010 that gets installed. Check out steps here : http://scissortools.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/how-to-make-sonar-runner-work-with-visual-studio-2012-and-2013/

Comment: @gpullen That says about errors. I am not getting gallio in add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my information, Gallio is not supported in VS2013.